# Glossaries-extra error with utf-8 encoding glossary entry

Tags: glossaries, glossaries-extra, utf8

I use glossaries-extra package to write my Glossary page, and it works well with English however when I insert an entry with utf-8 encoding, it raises an error.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage[automake]{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{ABC}
{name = ABC, 
description = {A programming language}                      
}
\newglossaryentry{Haskell}
{name = Haskell, 
description = {A programming language}                      
}
\longnewglossaryentry{Hello World}
{name = Hello World, 
description = {It's Hello World, you fool}                      
}
\newglossaryentry{biến}
{name = biến, 
description = {label for an information}                
}

\begin{document}
\Gls{ABC}, \Gls{Haskell}, \Gls{Hello World}. 

Trong Python, \gls{biến} là một nhãn để gán giá trị. 

\printglossary[nonumberlist]
\end{document}
```

How can I fix that to print out my glossary page properly?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You main problem is not `biến`, your main problem is, that you are using `\longnewglossaryentry` with only two instead of three argument. The command expects the `description` as third argument not only as key=value to the second one. To either use:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage[automake]{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{ABC}
{name = ABC, 
description = {A programming language}                      
}
\newglossaryentry{Haskell}
{name = Haskell, 
description = {A programming language}                      
}
\newglossaryentry{Hello World}
{name = Hello World, 
description = {It's Hello World, you fool}                      
}
\newglossaryentry{biến}
{name = biến, 
description = {label for an information}                
}

\begin{document}
\Gls{ABC}, \Gls{Haskell}, \Gls{Hello World}. 

Trong Python, \gls{biến} là một nhãn để gán giá trị. 

\printglossary[nonumberlist]
\end{document}
```

or

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage[automake]{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{ABC}
{name = ABC, 
description = {A programming language}                      
}
\newglossaryentry{Haskell}
{name = Haskell, 
description = {A programming language}                      
}
\newglossaryentry{Hello World}
{name = Hello World, 
description = {It's Hello World, you fool}                      
}
\longnewglossaryentry{biến}
{name = biến}{label for an information}                

\begin{document}
\Gls{ABC}, \Gls{Haskell}, \Gls{Hello World}. 

Trong Python, \gls{biến} là một nhãn để gán giá trị. 

\printglossary[nonumberlist]
\end{document}
```

I myself always prefer a kind of latin transcription for the *<entry-label>* argument of `\newglossaryentry`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage[automake]{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{ABC}
{name = ABC, 
description = {A programming language}                      
}
\newglossaryentry{Haskell}
{name = Haskell, 
description = {A programming language}                      
}
\newglossaryentry{Hello World}
{name = Hello World, 
description = {It's Hello World, you fool}                      
}
\newglossaryentry{bien}
{name = biến,
description = {label for an information}                
}

\begin{document}
\Gls{ABC}, \Gls{Haskell}, \Gls{Hello World}. 

Trong Python, \gls{bien} là một nhãn để gán giá trị. 

\printglossary[nonumberlist]
\end{document}
```

Comment: That works, thank you very much. I thought it was the utf9-encoding since everything was fine with English, the problem only arises when I insert that word.